# What is ⟕ (left outer join) of 3 relations that have no shared attributes?

Tags: database, left-join, rdbms, relational-algebra, cartesian-product

Consider 3 relations: r, p and e.

Consider r:

```
+-------+
| CD RD |
+-------+
|  1 11 |
|  2 22 |
|  3 33 |
+-------+
```

and p:

```
+-------+
| PD PR |
+-------+
| 1 U   |
| 2 C   |
| 3 S   |
+-------+
```

and e:

```
+---------+
| ED Name |
+---------+
| 1 B     |
| 2 BB    |
| 3 BBB   |
+---------+
```

What is r ⟕ p ⟕ e? It confuses me that they don't have shared attributes. Is this same as Cartesian product?

Comment: Hi. Please give a reference to the relational algebra you are asking about. There are many, with different operators & even notions of what a relation is. In particular give the definition of left outer join you are talking about. Do you mean left outer *natural* join? PS Read the definition of your left join & follow it. What do you get? Also: What do you get googling your title with 'stackoverflow.com'? (Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers.)

Answer (score 0):

(There are many different notions of RA (relational algebra), with different sets of operators, different definitions of operators with the same name, and different definitions of what a relation is. Also RA-inspired query languages get called "RA"s. This answer is phrased to apply to typical RAs--for natural or theta (restricted Cartesian product) inner & outer joins and for relations with headings that are sets or lists of attributes.)

Read a definition of left outer join. It returns the tuples of the corresponding inner join plus every non-participating left relation tuple extended by nulls. If there are no shared attributes for a natural join or an always-true condition for a theta join then the inner join returns every possible combination of a left relation tuple with a right relation tuple. (It is a so-called relational Cartesian product.) Since every left relation tuple participates, there are no additional tuples in the left outer join. So the left outer join is the same as the inner join (and right outer & inner join) and it is a Cartesian product. Similarly for right outer join. Full outer join is the union of left outer join & right outer join so in this case all three are equal.

Beware that for relations with headings that are sets (or ignoring column order for relations with headings that are lists): Although in general (inner) join is commutative (R join S = S join R) and associative (R join (S join T) = (R join S) join T), outer joins are not. So there is no "left outer join of 3 relations" unless you specify an application order. Full outer natural join is commutative. If multiple calls are on the same common attribute set then it is associative. (Then we can talk about "the" left outer natural join of multiple relations.)